# This code for a chat app says "expression expected" for the following line, how do I fix this?

Tags: java, reactjs

Using Visual Studio and reactjs.
There is this error as well as a message popping up saying that an expression is expected at const and a Parsing error: Unexpected token. This is in the bolded section

Thanks for the help

> Parsing Error: Unexpected token for the comma

```js
class messages extends Component {
   render(){
       const{messages} = this.props;
       return (
           <ul className="messages-list">
           {messages.map( m => this.renderMessage(m))}
           renderMessage(message) {

**const {member, text}= message;
 const {currentMember} = this.props;
 const messageFromMe = member.id === currentMember.id;
 const className = messageFromMe ?**
   "Messages-message currentMember" : "Messages-message";

 return (
   <li className={className}>
     <span
       className="avatar"
       style={{backgroundColor: member.clientData.color}}
     />
     <div className="Message-content">
       <div className="username">
         {member.clientData.username}
       </div>
       <div className="text">{text}</div>
     </div>
   </li>
 );
}

           </ul>

       )
   }
}

export default messages;
```

Comment: A bracket seems to be missing in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code fixed:

```js
class Messages extends Component {
  renderMessage(message) {
    const { member, text } = message;
    const { currentMember } = this.props;
    const messageFromMe = member.id === currentMember.id;
    const className = messageFromMe
      ? "Messages-message currentMember"
      : "Messages-message";

    return (
      <li className={className}>
        <span
          className="avatar"
          style={{ backgroundColor: member.clientData.color }}
        />
        <div className="Message-content">
          <div className="username">{member.clientData.username}</div>
          <div className="text">{text}</div>
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  }
  render() {
    const { messages } = this.props;
    return (
      <ul className="messages-list">
        {messages.map(m => this.renderMessage(m))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default Messages;
```

You are doing a few things wrong:

1. Your class name should start with a capital letter.
2. You are inserting a function inside the render function, thats wrong, define it before.